# How to set 644 file permissions for newly created files and 755 for newly created directories?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, file-permissions

I have an e-commerce site in Magento. When I upload a file using the administrator, the folder is created with 770 permissions, and the actual file is also created with 770 permissions.

Cause of this, when apache tries to read the file, it shows a forbidden error.

How can I make the file to be created by default with 644 permission and folder with 775?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When a file is created in a web page, permissions set are not compatible with Apache user. How can I fix this?](http://superuser.com/questions/1017664/when-a-file-is-created-in-a-web-page-permissions-set-are-not-compatible-with-ap) (which does not have an answer)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have different umask for files and directories by default as [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445527/set-different-umask-for-files-and-folders) says. You can check your current umask just by typing umask at the terminal. It defaults to 0022 on most distros and this is probably what you want. I like to use umask 0007 when I'm being paranoid to lock it down a little.

It sounds weird that files are also created with 7 (execute) permissions as that is not normal behaviour. Usually, with a umask of 0022, files are created as 644 and directories are created as 755.

The only reasons for this weird umask I can think of are that someone set it manually (in the global bashrc file for example) or in the /etc/fstab file for the mounted filesystem. In /etc/fstab you can have both fmask and dmask for files and directories, respectively.

If you really do want different umasks for files and directories I'd try something like the aforementioned answer proposed:
Have a default umask of 0022 and then an alias when creating directories:

```
alias mkdir='umask 002; mkdir'
```